# Function to seperate positives from negatives

Tags: python, list

I have this exercise from a list, return two list's one with positive numbers and the other with negative.

My code:

```
def fuc(list):
  negatives = []
  positives = []

  for i in list:
      if i > 0:
          positives.append(i)
          print(i)
      else:
          negatives.append(i)
          print(i)

print(fuc([1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5]))
```

This code doesn't return 2 list's(negative and positive), I want to know how I get 2 list's from the original list.

Comment: Just add an `else` to your loop and decide which list `0` belongs in. Cheers

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Now just add `return negatives, positives` Done!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `else` keyword and returning the values would work, but there's a nicer approach using ternary expression to determine which list to append to:

```
def func(l):
  negatives = []
  positives = []

  for i in l:
      (positives if i >= 0 else negatives).append(i):

  return negatives,positives
```

That is, if you consider `0` as positive, else you'd have to filter it out and the interest would be limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the choice of using numpy you can do something like this.

```
import numpy as np

def fuc(myList):
    myList=np.array(myList)
    neg=myList[np.less(myList,0)]
    pos=myList[np.greater(myList,0)]
    return list(neg),list(pos)
```